# Paywall content in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am using DNN 9.3.2 and Evoq 9.3.7.

I would like to paywall content in a section of the website with teaser content i.e. so that they can read a part of the article but need to pay/ log in to access the content. 'Members' would also need to be able to log in and bypass the paywall. Users would idealy be able to manage their account from here. The paywall would also need to be able to handle a complex pricing model i.e. different prices for different user types, possibly different content available for different user types.

Would anyone be able to advise how best to do this with DNN/ Evoq, and which modules from DNN store (if any) would be useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, but in theory any shop solution should give you that functionality. Have a look at [OpenStore](https://github.com/openstore-ecommerce/OpenStore), which is Open Source and free.

Or a News/Blog module that supports paid content, as [EasyDnnNews](https://www.easydnnsolutions.com/products/dnn-modules/easydnnnews).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to brew your own or ask a specialist who knows what they are doing already. The basic principle is as follows:

1. Protect a page with a role - let's call it `Patrons` which only paying users will get
2. Create a page for users to pay on, and if successful, assign them the role
3. You can also do things like ensure that the role is only given for a certain time, and then the users must pay again.
4. If you have a subscription model, you would probably run a timer job or something to verify payments have happened again, and if true, extend the role assignment